# How to use the same element in differents HTML pages in which it has different configuration?

Tags: html, css, rules

general questions :
If I stylised an element that belong to,le's say index.html and then I want to use it in a second page but, it will have different position for example. If I set the new rules that will destroy the former one. How can one figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this a few ways but I will name a few here:

1. Use inline styles - If it is a very small change e.g. as in your case, just to change the position value of an element, you can override the style in your original stylesheet by adding an inline style to the element, like so:

```
<p style="left: 0;">...</p>
```

2. Create a new stylesheet for the modifications - In your new HTML page, where you would link the original stylesheet in the head of the document, add a new link *after* it that will hold the styles you'd like to make/adjust just for that page. Make sure you place it after the original, so that the styles will override those in the original stylesheet.

In this stylesheet, you would target the element as you would normally in your original, but just place the property and value you would like to add/change.

3. Add another class to the element (assuming you already have one in the first place to style the element) For example, if you wanted to change the value of the left position of the element all the way to the left side, you could create a class that could be called `left-0` to clearly describe the "purpose/action" like so:

```
<p class="otherClasses left-0">...</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie. It's all clear now. The 2nd and the 3rd seem to be more efficient.

I wonder if it is the same if we have some p and hx but with differents rules? I'm trying to work with SASS but it's difficult to gather the same rules in order to build mixins!!! it really disrupts me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean if it's the same with p and hx rules @MassineOueslati, what kind of mixins are you trying to create with Sass?